# Open Source Barcode Scanner in C?

Tags: c, webcam, barcode

I'm looking for any open-source software out there that takes an webcam stream and scans for a barcode, returning the value of the barcode in the current frame, if any. It would be preferred if it was in C, but any other languages are welcome. Note, I am not interested in using a mobile phone or a separate barcode scanner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) has Java and C++ ports. If you need to call it from C, you can always write a shim in C++ that exposed plain C calls.

ZXing is used a lot on mobile platforms but there's nothing inherently mobile in the core. You'd need to provide the appropriate interfaces for the platform that capture the video stream and call the ZXing functions. Not exactly what you need but see ,for example, [ZXing.app](https://github.com/smparkes/zxing.app).

The C++ port of ZXing has some support for 1D barcodes and is solid for QR codes. (1D codes are also more difficult to scan using webcams which are often fairly fixed-focus and low resolution.)